# Service worker is not registered or does not control Start URL

Tags: angular, angular5, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Chrome Manifest tab:

[image]

I don't see any service worker either, Chrome Service Worker tab:

[image]

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "short_name": "shortname",
    "name": "Full Name",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "img/logo.svg",
        "type": "image/svg",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "background_color": "#cc2366",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "theme_color": "#cc2366"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js') : [],
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

.angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    ...
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      ...
      "serviceWorker": true,
      ...
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    ...
  },
  "lint": [
    ...
  ],
  "test": {
    ...
  },
  "defaults": {
    ...
  }
}
```

However I am able to access `https://myrooturl/ngsw-worker.js` via browser.

What am I missing?

(disc: some non relevant codes are shown dotted )

Comment: Service workers are only available with HTTPS, otherwise they won't register.

Comment: No worries there. updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your [syntax](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/ServiceWorkerModule) is wrong.  It should be.

```
  imports: [
    ...
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }) : [],
    ...
  ],
```

Comment: thats not the issue, I posted the error from production

Comment: is angular adding the 'navigator.serviceWorker.register' to your source?

Comment: actually that way of writing was wrong, enabling production should be argument, this fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54996593/865220

Comment: that's great you found the answer!  i changed my answer to be correct for next peoples that come across this.

Comment: But now I am stuck with a different issue, maybe you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797611/swupdate-isenabled-is-true-but-not-calling-the-subscribed-method-even-when-ngsw